# Are there a closed form of near solutions to the equation: $2\sigma(n)=3n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I would like to check the solution of this equation:

$$2\sigma(n)=3n$$ where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum divisor function.

**Note**: I know only $n=2$ is a theortitical  solution, are there a closed form of near  solution of the titled equation  ?

for example until now i find this :$n={29}^{16}+1$

**EDIT**:I edited the question because it is related to the precedent question

Comment: That $n=29^{16}+1$ is not a solution. It can't be, by the below proof.

Comment: I meant appraoch as i said before to u

Comment: So, your question is not whether there is an $n>2$ such that $2\sigma(n)=3n$? What is the point of "approach." And what do you mean by "approach." You see to be missing that the question you have asked has been answered.

Comment: What do you mean by an approach solution?  It sounds like maybe you mean $2 \sigma(n)$ is approximately equal to $3n$.  If so, how close do you mean?

Comment: In general, any number that is twice a prime will be "close." That doesn't mean it is a solution. You will have $2\sigma(n)=3n+3$ in that case. You can't get any closer. So $\sigma(n)/n = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{n}$, which is as close as you can get for even $n$.

Comment: ok, i meant example :sigma(29^16+1)/(29^16+1) =1.500002222

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: You haven't edited the question in such a way as to make it clear what you really want. The below shows there is no solution, yet you suddenly are talking about "near" solutions.

Comment: yes ,exactly ,this what i meant ,

Comment: @ i edited the question, and i indicated "appraoch solution

Comment: But your question does not indicate that. How close is "near enough" for you? You haven't asked that question. If you want to ask another question, edit your question to mean what you want. Sigh

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Approach is not a mathematical term. It is hard to know what you want in using that term.

Comment: As Thomas Andrews says, there is nothing special about $29^{16}+1$ except that it is twice an odd prime.  You should have been able to figure out the error of $3$ from ttt's answer as any number of the form $n=2p, p$ an odd prime will have factors $1,2,p,2p$ and $\sigma(n)=\frac 32n+3$

Comment: Perhaps you meant this question: "I know the only solution to $2\sigma(n)=3n$ is $n=2$. What about numbers $n$ such that $2\sigma(n)$ is close to $3n$?" If that is what you meant, you'd have to answer the question of what you mean by "close to." There actually might be odd $n$ that get closer than $3$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm not even sure that number is prime - the error OP gets from $\sigma(n)/n-3/2$ is much more than $3/n$.

Comment: 29^16+1 is even number

Comment: We know that, @zeraouliarafik

Comment: I have a nice closed form which the error is very small , but since my question is not apperaed to be clear i let it

Comment: It's not very small relative to the size of $n=29^{16}+1$. There are numbers of similiar size where the error is $3/n$. The error you gave isn't even $3/\sqrt{n}$. And you still haven't updated your question to make clear what you are asking.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigma%28173^16%2B1%29%2F%28173^16%2B1%29

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+29%5E16%2B1) says $29^{16}+1$ is twice a prime.  OP's value for the relative error is wrong.  I get the relative error to be about [$1.2 \cdot 10^{-23}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F%28+29%5E16%2B1%29)

Comment: @RossMillikan, then is it a near solution ?

Comment: You haven't defined what a near solution is, @zeraouliarafik So how can we answer you? You won't define your terms, so this, so far, is not a math question.

Comment: 1.2*10^(-23)  , in my opinion is 0

Comment: As I said before, for any odd prime $p$ you have $\sigma (2p)=\frac 32 (2p)+3$.  Your $29^{16}+1$ is twice a prime, so it fits this.  Any other number twice an odd prime will have the same absolute error of $3$ or relative error of $3/n$  The larger the prime, the smaller the relative error.  AND NO, $1.2 \cdot 10^{-23} \neq 0$

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Then you are not doing mathematics if a non-zero value is zero. And that is why you have to define near solution.

Comment: Ah, for no particular reason, I assumed OP could actually do the calculation correctly. @RossMillikan

Comment: And, of course a "near solution" of $2\sigma(n)=3n$ might mean something different from a "near solution" of $\sigma(n)/n=3/2$. Because we have no idea what you mean by "near solution" to an equation, because you won't define it. @zeraouliarafik

Comment: I don't understand how this hasn't been closed already.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: FWIW, one English error in your question is the sentence "I know only $n=2$ is a theoretical answer." The word "only" in that sentence seems to apply to "know." As in, "The only answer I know is..." which means there might be other answers. A correct English sentence with the meaning you (seem to) intend: "I know that $n=2$ is the only answer." Every native English speaker reads that sentence as implying you were looking for more answers. @zeraouliarafik Also, "theoretical" is a confusing word. You mean "exact answer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a near solution, you can look at $21$.  We have $\sigma(21)=1+3+7+21=32$, so $2\sigma(21)=64=3(21)+1$.  You won't get any less absolute error than that.  You can find near solutions with much smaller relative error.  Let $n$ be a product of large primes $n=pqr\dots z$  Then $\frac {\sigma(n)}n = 1+\frac 1p + \frac 1q +\frac 1r +\dots \frac 1z +\frac 1{pq}+\frac 1{pr}+\dots$  Start from some large prime (maybe your friend $\frac 12(29^{16}+1)$) and keep multiplying by successive primes until the right side is very close to $\frac 32$  As the sum of the inverses of the primes diverges, you can always exceed $\frac 32$ by taking enough of them, no matter how high you start.  It will take a lot of them.  You can tune it even closer by deleting the one that takes you just over $\frac 32$ and looking for the next larger prime that fits underneath $\frac 32$

For example, starting with the "large prime" $17$ I find $$17*19*23*29*31*37*41*43*47*53*59*61*67*71*73=1356299720254712758928449\\ \sigma(1356299720254712758928449)=2034799419064923979776000\\
2*2034799419064923979776000-3*1356299720254712758928449=699677365709682766653$$
with a relative error of about$\frac {7 \cdot 10^{20}}{2*2034799419064923979776000} \approx 0.000017$  You can improve that by replacing $73$ with $79$, then adding in much larger primes to get close to the ratio $\frac 32$.  I don't trust the precision in Excel that far.

Comment: "You won't get any less absolute error than that." What about 9, 27, or for the matter of fact any power 3, all of which has the same $1/2$ absolute error and much smaller relative errors?

Comment: @NimaBavari:  Once I found one case of the minimum possible absolute error, I quit looking.  I then turned to looking to show we could get the relative error arbitrarily small. Your approach gets the relative error small faster than mine does, but both work to show we can.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no other solutions.

Let $n\ge 3$ be an answer for this equation.
It is obvious that $n$ must be even.
So $1$, $n/2$, $n$ are divisors of $n$ (and $n/2>1$).
Sum of these is $3n/2 + 1 > 3n/2$.
So there is no answer other than $2$.

Comment: this is not a proof , you must learn more about divisor function

Comment: Why not, zeraoulia rafik?

Comment: look,your equation tells that sum of divisors of n ,equals 3n/2.I showed that for n>4 we have no answer.because 1,n/2,n,... divide n

Comment: @kamilo, take this number n=29^16 +1

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Don't be rude in correcting people. It's particularly embarrassing when you are the one wrong. Your $n$ is dividisible by $1,2,n,n/2$ so $\sigma(n)\geq 1+2+n+n/2 >\frac{3}{2}n$. So $2\sigma(n)>3n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you , if you take as example n=29^16+1 ,sigma(n)/n closed to 3/2

Comment: It's still greater than $3/2$ so is not a solution. I don't see your point in obsessing about that one number. This answer notes that (1) A solution must be even, (2) Any even number greater than $4$ has $2\sigma(n)> 3n$. Your question does not ask about "close." You asked about solutions to $2\sigma(n)=3n$. This answer shows there are no more solutions other than $n=2$. @zeraouliarafik

Comment: thanks, must to edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\sigma_{-1} (n) = \sigma (n)/n$. Also, we need to define what "close" means. We look for such $n$ that $$f (n) := |\sigma_{-1} (n) - 3/2| < \varepsilon_n,$$ where $\varepsilon_n \to 0$ is predefined (depending o how close you want). We also note $n > 2$.

Let $n$ be a prime. Then, $\sigma_{-1} (n) = 1 + 1/n$ so, $f (n) = 1/2 - 1/n$.

Assume now $n$ is a prime power, i.e., $n = p^{\alpha}$ for a positive integer $\alpha$ and a prime $p > 2$. Then, $$\sigma_{-1} (n) = 1 + \frac {1} {n^{1/\alpha}} + \frac {1} {n^{2/\alpha}} \cdots + \frac {1} {n}$$ and $$f (n) = \frac {1} {2} - \left (\frac {1} {n^{1/\alpha}} + \frac {1} {n^{2/\alpha}} \cdots + \frac {1} {n}\right ).$$ Then, $f (3^\alpha) \to 0$ as $\alpha \to \infty$. Hence, $n = 3^\alpha$ is a solution and you get closer and closer as $\alpha$ gets bigger. For example, all $3^\alpha$ where $\alpha > N$ are solutions to your problem.

Now, suppose $n$ is squarefree, i.e, $n = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$. Then, $$\sigma_{-1} (n) = 1 + \left (\frac {1} {p_1} + \frac {1} {p_2} + \cdots + \frac {1} {p_k} \right) + \cdots + \frac {1} {n}.$$ But this gets larger than we want actually, and we can prove that $\sigma_{-1} (n) \to 3$. To see that, notice $\sigma_{-1} (p_1 \cdots p_{k + 1}) > \sigma_{-1} (p_1 \cdots p_{k})$. Hence, $f (n) \to \frac {3} {2}$ as $k \to \infty$.

Now, let $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ for $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots > 1$. Then $\sigma_{-1} (n) > \sigma_{-1} (p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k)$, so no solution here, either.

So, the only solution is $n = 3^\alpha$.

Note that here I assumed you want to keep and actually improve the speed of your approximation with the growth of $n$. Otherwise, there are infinitely many scattered arbitrary solutions to the problem, which makes the problem ill-defined. For example, $n = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 31 \cdot 257$ is a fine approximation.

Comment: My question  decrease with vote and the answers  increases

Comment: @zeraouliarafik How about my solution? Is it what you had in mind? Also, I started typing just as you posted the question, but apparently I got late and my answer came the last.

Comment: your answer is best and i will accept it , but it is very hard to show thata things is the only satisfies

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Read again. I gave the class of solutions ONLY which gives better and better approximations as $n$ grows bigger, which is the only way to make the problem well-defined.